# spring: can I autowire fields of component fields?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Given:

```
@Component
class Foo {}

class Bar {
   @Autowired
   Foo foo;
}

@Component
class Zoo {
   Bar bar = new Bar();
}
```

How can I insttruct Spring to autowire the field `foo` in the `bar` instance?

More specifically, can I instruct spring to treat Bar as a bean once it sees an instance. E.g,, respect `@PostConstruct` annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring is able to wire classes annotated with @Configurable using aspectj for compile time weaving. In maven (taken from configuration created by Roo):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <!-- NB: do not use 1.3 or 1.3.x due to MASPECTJ-90 and do not use 1.4 due to declare parents issue  -->
            <dependencies>
                <!-- NB: You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see MNG-2972) -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outxml>true</outxml>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and in the application context add `<context:spring-configured/>`

Answer (score 1):

You have set it by hand, since by using `new` you're creating objects which are not managed by Spring IOC container.

It also won't respect `@PostContruct` as that annotation only works for beans managed by containers.

Answer (score 0):

why cant it be

```
@Component
class Zoo {
    @Autowired
    Bar bar;
}

 @Component
 class Bar {
    @Autowired
    Foo foo;
 }
```

Comment: because i don't want to make it a "root" bean. also, in my case, creating the class passes the 'this' parameter of Zoo and it is a prototype bean

Comment: what do you mean by "root" bean?